# any why in node red import api available

Tags: node-red

I am working on customizing node red and I want to automate the functionality of import.

1. When I select Export from right top menu in node red
2. Attached screenshot will display
3. Here I want to select Current Flow and get that json automatically so is there any way to get this json?

I don't want to use any copy to clipboard or download.

[image]

Comment: What you have described is exporting the flow, not importing. Which is it you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

The [Admin API](https://nodered.org/docs/api/admin/methods/) provides ways to both retrieve/deploy new flows to/from the backend.

GET requests to `/flows` returns the current running flow

POST requests to `/flows` deploys the flow in the POST body